# Cycling through mysql data?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a website for funny images. Those images are stored in a file in the server. I have a database that contain all the information for all of those images (name in the file, type, views, likes, dislikes, reports, and so on).

I want to use the name of that image as my url `www.example.com/name_of_the_image` and when I click on the image it will take me to the next (image page) so each image will have its own unique url.

I already tried to pass the id of the image from the database to the url and keep browsing the images but it seemed unprofessional way to do what I want to achieve.

Now what is the best and efficient way to do this ? Any ideas ?

Comment: I already tried to pass the id of the image from the data base to the url and keep browsing the images but it seemed unprofessional way to do what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ’slugs’.
have an extra field with your database image data called slug.
everytime you upload an image store it using the slug(usually a slug is the title in lowercase with underscores instead of spaces).
Then use .htaccess to rewrite your urls to something pretty that uses the slug to retrieve the info.
www.host.com/images/cat_in_a_pickle_jar
points to
www.host.com/displayimage.php?slug=cat_in_a_pickle_jar